# How to work with MySQL auto increment columns?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, sqlexception

I am try to use MySQL `auto_increment` in a Java program. But I'm getting this type of error:

```
Sep 09, 2017 7:36:16 PM demosub jButton1ActionPerformed SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1
```

This is my program:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/anadha";
        String uname1 = "root";
        String password = "csrajesh";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, uname1, password);
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("INSERT into employee (time, name) VALUES (?,?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        pst.setString(2, nme.getText());
        pst.executeUpdate();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(demosub.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(demosub.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: Get it working in a command line app. first, then it should work pretty much exactly the same way *"in java swing program"*.

Comment: which column is auto increment, time or name or any other?

Comment: Please provide the structure of the table you are attempting to insert into.
It would be easiest to understand as a CREATE statement but make sure we can tell which column is an auto_increment column and the types of each column.

Comment: +-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to bind the first parameter therefore the error. You only set the value for the 2nd parameter

```
pst.setString(2, nme.getText());
```

You should have another line saying sth like :

```
pst.setString(1, "ValueYouWant");
```

Or

```
pst.setTimestamp(1, <function_that_returns_a_timestamp>);
```

Depending on what type of value is expected for that column.

If you do not want to add the current timestamp yourself just set the `time` column default value to be CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in the table.

Comment: @rajeshdeva the problem may be a disconnect between the table structure and the assumptions your code is making. I highly recommend updating your question with SQL of the table (a CREATE statement would work well). 
If you aren't sure how to get the SQL just describe the table & columns as accurately as you can.